# Randomness of submolecular phenomena

Tags: kinetic-theory, brownian-motion, randomness

Why do models of submolecular phenomena involving randomness work?  Do these phenomena appear random to other submolecular particles?

For example, people can use [Einstein-Smoluchowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)) to characterize ion diffusion through solutions: this model is based on the assumption of a random walk.  Do ions in a solution view the movements of other ions as random?

Comment: Are you looking for a theoretical proof (if so, look up Mori-Zwanzig theory), or a qualitative explanation?

Comment: Both would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the equations of motion with collisions behave chaotically and from an observers point of view behave randomly. What can be shown is that there is some structure in that chaos, for instance, the distribution of energies among the molecules follow the  [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). This probability distribution indicates which speeds are more likely: a particle will have a speed selected randomly from the distribution, and is more likely to be within one range of speeds than another. The distribution depends on the temperature of the system and the mass of the particle.

Comment: The answer does not answer the question of "why", but rather blindly uses statements of very limited scope (equilibrium thermodynamics) that at best might be applied to explaining some of the consequences, but as I understand the question, certainly not the underlying reasons. This is particularly unfortunate as the question is asking about the processes themselves, modeled with Langevin equations etc. which are manifestly non-equilibrium. What is essential here are correlations and time scales, and the answer in its present state does not even mention these.

Comment: @alarge I answered these "Do ions in a solution view the movements of other ions as random?" "Do these phenomena appear random to other submolecular particles?", if you think there are questions that I did not noticed, I encourage you to write an answer to them.

Comment: the why too, it is because the solutions ar chaotic.

Comment: Q: "Why do models of submolecular phenomena involving randomness work?" A: "Because the phenomena are chaotic". This is hardly a satisfying explanation even if you meant chaotic to be interpreted in the technical  sense of the word (rather than as a synonym for random as one might easily read it). Furthermore, the arguments of your answer apply equally well for solids (they, too, obey the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution). Given this, are you suggesting that the movements of the atoms of a solid appear random to one another?

Comment: No, you reversed the logic, I pointed out that the chaotic (in the formal sense) solutions look random, but even if so they still have some structure, like the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution, instead of being uniform. And that is important when you model a random walk.

Comment: We seem to have a disagreement about the nature of randomness (which would make a good question). Is a random process obeying M-B "less random" (has more order) than a process obeying some other distribution? I do not think so, and as M-B implies nothing of (displacement) correlations, I don't think your answer adequately covers the question. Also, M-B is only valid for equilibrium, which is not typically the case when one uses stochastic modeling. You pointed out that the eqs of motion are chaotic, but this doesn't explain why one can find effective stochastic formulations for the phenomena.

Comment: I agree, this is a topic perhaps for another question, and I'd be glad to discuss it there. But I think (I might be wrong) that this is beyond the scope of this question. But you should answer your viewpoint, the more answers the better!